# Display array name with the array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Below is my array

```
{
    "finalArray": [
        {"name": "John"},
        {"name": "Pascal"},
        {"name": "Robert"}
    ]
}
```

But when I use console.log(finalArray) this is what I get

```
{
     [
        {"name": "John"},
        {"name": "Pascal"},
        {"name": "Robert"}
    ]
}
```

My question is how do I display the array with "finalArray" in console ?

@symlink - Your solution worked for me but I would like to know how do I change this for your soultion

```
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push({"name": names[i]});
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think that second output is even valid Javascript. What repl are you using to view your console log?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan - Without that name it says invalid json

Comment: Ya, that would make sense.  How are you running your code?

Comment: Are you doing this `console.log(finalArray)` and not this `console.log(finalArray["finalArray"])`?

Comment: @symlink - this gives me undefined

Comment: @Kitty See my answer. I presented three possibilities and how they would output in console.log. Do any look familiar?

Comment: That tool is used to generate docx, pptx and xlsx files. What are you trying to do exactly? If you really did just want to view this array why use this method over dev tools or running your file locally?

Comment: Don't change your question after you have received answers. Instead, (roll back your edit, accept one of the answers you got, and) ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements, and probably a link back to here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const names = ["John", "Pascal", "Robert"]

const finalArray = {
  finalArray: []
}

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    finalArray["finalArray"].push({"name": names[i]});
}

console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: Thanks your soultion worked and I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: @Kitty See my edit. Basically you need to create an object with a key named "finalArray" and a value of an empty array.

Answer (score -2):

please use mapping to display name like-

```
const {finalArray} = myArray
const displayName = finalArray.map((name)=>name.name)
console.log(displayName)
```

Hope this will help you, if you still facing issue, lemme know i will help you more..